# What is it called when two people refuse to talk to each other?

Tags: word-choice

What is it called when two people (usually kids) stop talking for a while after a fight or an argument because they are mad at each other?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

As zondo says, above, such people ***aren't speaking to each other***.  (This is pretty much true even if they do literally say a few words for logistical reasons -- "I need to get out.  Move your car" -- as long as they are doing what they can to avoid speaking.)

People ***aren't on speaking terms*** if they are doing this as a sort of policy long-term.  You wouldn't say that if they're just too angry to speak for a couple of days, but you would if months go by and they are deliberately avoiding speaking.

The ***silent treatment*** is a deliberate plan to punish the other party by being silent, as opposed to avoiding speaking for some other reason (like being too angry or hurt to converse).

Such people may also be ***avoiding each other***, but that doesn't imply anger.

Comment: "Not on speaking terms" is the only phrase I can think of that clearly describes the mutuality, or reciprocity, of the silence, which I think distinguishes this phrase from all of the suggestions thus far.

Comment: @hunterhogan How does "aren't speaking to each other" not indicate that it's mutual?

Answer (score 35):

This sounds like a classic case of the [***silent treatment***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silent_treatment).

> Silent treatment (often referred to as the silent treatment) is verbal silence imposed onto another. It may range from just sulking to malevolent abusive controlling behaviour. It may be a passive-aggressive form of emotional abuse in which displeasure, disapproval and contempt is exhibited through nonverbal gestures while maintaining verbal silence. Clinical psychologist Harriet Braiker identifies it as a form of manipulative punishment.

*Wikipedia*

This could be used to refer to either one person not talking to another, or with two people they'd be giving *each other* the silent treatment, but zondo's comment of "not on speaking terms" is also valid.

Comment: The Wikipedia article confirms my gut feeling that *the silent treatment* is something one person (or group) imposes on another, and includes refusing to acknowledge attempts by the second party to communicate.  Therefore, the idea of two people giving each other the silent treatment strikes me as something of an oxymoron.

Comment: @Scott [I](http://wrightliving.com/couples-give-silent-treatment) [could](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/20141021144107-360049-couples-why-you-shouldn-t-give-each-other-the-silent-treatment) [possibly](http://www.ibtimes.co.in/beyonce-jay-z-giving-each-other-silent-treatment-rumours-marriage-trouble-continue-plague-671851) [beg](http://www.cbssports.com/nfl/eye-on-football/25465422/johnny-manziel-and-hue-jackson-are-giving-each-other-the-silent-treatment) [to](https://www.reddit.com/r/offmychest/comments/3qik1l/husband_and_i_are_giving_each_other_the_silent/) differ. :)

Comment: @Scott I have to agree. I've never heard of the "silent treatment" being a mutual thing between 2 people. I've always heard it used as something one person does to another. I'm not saying that it's necessarily correct, but it's the only usage of the phrase I've ever heard.

Comment: @Carcigenicate - If I'm mad at someone, I might give them the silent treatment. If the feelings are mutual, we might give each other the silent treatment – as is discussed at length in [this blog post](http://wrightliving.com/couples-give-silent-treatment). Since hurt feelings often run bidirectionally, this isn't all that uncommon.

Comment: @Scott consider, you can't stop me from giving you the silent treatment by giving me the silent treatment.  I don't need you to attempt to communicate to ignore you.  We can sit in the same room silently brooding at each other.  What the OP describes is indeed two people giving each other the silent treatment.

Comment: IMHO the silent treatment is a form of psychopathic/narcissistic abuse, there are always an abuser and a victim, I don't understand how this can be mutual.

Comment: Imagine for a second that two people have an argument. Afterwards, they both decide at the same time to stop talking to the other because they're too angry. Would you *not* say this is them giving each other the silent treatment?

Comment: i downvoted because the 'silent treatment' is what one person gives another, when the other person wants to communicate. Two people don't give each other the silent treatment, instead they are 'not talking' or 'not speaking'.

Comment: @SteveIves See above, where I linked several instances of people referred to as "giving each other the silent treatment". It's more common than you think.

Comment: @JohnClifford - In the UK, I still think it's more usual to say that they are not talking, rather than they are giving each other the silent treatment.

Comment: @SteveIves I'm from the UK, and have said people were giving each other the silent treatment before. I appreciate the reason for your downvote, though, and thanks for your input.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37910/discussion-between-john-clifford-and-joe-blow).

Comment: "The silent treatment" was the first thing that came to my mind as well. The silent treatment is something one person does to another. There is nothing that limits it to being unidirectional. Consider the word "punch".  A punch has a puncher and a punchee. That doesn't stop two people from punching each other. Why would the silent treatment be any different?

Comment: A few more supporting references: [1](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/silent+treatment), [2](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/silent%20treatment), [3](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/silent-treatment), [4](https://www.wordnik.com/words/silent%20treatment), [5](http://dictionary.infoplease.com/silent-treatment), [6](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/silent-treatment).

Answer (score 18):

You could also say that they are giving each other the cold shoulder.

Comment: To give someone the cold shoulder is broader than just not speaking to them; it's to dismiss them altogether, or to be completely indifferent to them.

Answer (score 7):

For two kids, you can say they are **sulking.**  Sulk, defined by [Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sulk)

> to be angry or upset about something and to refuse to discuss it with
>   other people

Comment: I think sulking has more to do with basking in self-pity than not talking.

Comment: Merriam-Webster disagrees  :D                                                     >www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sulking

Comment: I added the reference and the link.  Please note that answers here are supposed to have a reference and, if an online reference, a link.

Comment: The dictionary definition you quote doesn't really support your answer if taken literally. It says they will reuse to discuss that particular issue that makes them upset, not be silent in general.

Comment: I think that if I am glaring or looking daggers at you across the room and I refuse to talk to you I am not sulking.  If we've had an argument and I stalk off to my room and refuse to come out and talk to you *then* I'm sulking.

Comment: Sulking is not correct. sulking is what one person does to show their displeasure with something and it affects their behavior towards everyone, not just one other person that they are upset with.

Answer (score 5):

An **estrangement** or to be **estranged**, but this is usually reserved for when there is an emotional distance due to some unresolvable turmoil in a familial/spousal context, not usually used for pouting children. An estrangement can be one-sided, mutual, or involving more than 2 parties.

Answer (score 3):

You might consider, ***fall out***

> To break a relationship or form a negative relationship as a result of a dispute.
>
> **fall out with someone**; **have a falling-out with someone**
>
> To break a relationship or form a negative relationship with someone.
>
> [The American Heritage® Dictionary of Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/fall+out)

Comment: 'Fall out' is incorrect - 2 friends might 'fall out' which leads to them not talking or not speaking, but the act of not communicating is not the 'fall out', rather it is a consequence of the falling out.

Comment: Indeed, you might fall out with someone, but still *have to* communicate with them.

Answer (score 1):

If the mutual silence is due to an impasse in an argument, the silence can be referred to as a *[standoff](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/standoff)*:

> An argument, contest, etc., in which there is no winner

In this case, there is no "winner" because there is no resolution.

This is related to the personality descriptor *standoffish*: such a person is inclined to reserved or silent disagreement rather than pursuit of a resolution or compromise.

Answer (score 0):

If both parties are waiting for the other to break the silence first, it is sometimes colloquially referred to as a Mexican Standoff.

Comment: This is by extension. "Mexican Standoff" refers to a situation where several people are pointing guns at one another.

Answer (score 0):

Since the context is "usually kids", you can say that they are *snubbing* each other.

> **Snub** *verb*
>   1 Rebuff, ignore, or spurn disdainfully: *he snubbed faculty members and students alike*
>   [- ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/snub)

Answer (score -1):

In my country(South américa, Chile) it´s popular to call it "Ice Law" or "Ley del Hielo" (ignoring each other).

Answer (score -2):

There is also **Excommunication**, which has deep roots in religion, but is also used in contemporary contexts, in much the same way as the "Sent to Coventry" referenced in other answers.

Comment: Excommunication strictly applies to banishment or expulsion from a church, almost exclusively christian churches.  There really are no other general uses of the word.  Perhaps you're thinking of [incommunicado](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/incommunicado)?

Comment: I disagree with your assertion that it is *strictly* used in church contexts. Eg. "The management team isn't talking to me, it's like I've been excommunicated". To me, incommunicado implies that both parties are mutually not in contact with each other, whereas excommunication is very much one sided.

Comment: I would call that usage explicit simile, it doesn't counter the point.  For example, I could say, *"Being stabbed with an obsidian blade was like being electrocuted"*.  That doesn't at all imply that "electrocuted" is a suitable word to use for being stabbed, generally.

Comment: Yes, it was an explicit simile, for the purposes of making it explicit, but I've definitely seen implicit usage, in the same way that a non-Catholic person can say "I need to confess my sins" even though they can't possibly have sinned and they have no intention of talking to a priest. "That deluded forum mod has excommunicated me".